I am trying to upgrade angular version from 16 to 17 but it throws below error when I run npm start
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i11.MatLegacySelectModule to symbol

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i11.MatLegacySelectModule to symbol

I have changed all the required packages. Can someone tell what to do?

Since Angular Material v17, the legacy components are not available anymore, see the Angular v17 announcement. Either perform the MDC migration, or stay on Angular Material v16 while updating the other Angular packages to v17.
